# postgresql select query in procedure is not working with dynamic value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgresql procedure. I am trying to create following function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE

        server1 varchar(200);
        server2 varchar(200);
    BEGIN
        select substr(server,0,3) into server1 from traveler_data where userid='123abc';
        select server into server2 from traveler_server_details where geagraphy='India' and server ilike '%server1%' ;
        update email_automation set serverurl_abc=server2 where userid='123abc';
      insert into email_automation values('1245',server1,server2);
return;
      END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

problem I am facing is update and insert is working fine with the server1 dynamic value which I am getting from first select statement .But second select statement is not returning server2 value with  server1 dynamic value.It is returning null .Due to that I am not able to update or insert server2 value. any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server ilike '%server1%'` looks for the value `server1` in that column, not for value that is stored in the variable

You want

```
server ilike '%'||server1||'%'
```